# Generate Sequence Diagrams with systems as lifeline in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, use-case, sequence-diagram

I'm a total beginner to Enterprise Architect (last version) and I'm stuck with a little problem.

I made some use cases with a system boundary. I tried to generate sequence diagrams with my actors communicating with the system. But, because the system isn't an actor, I can't find it in the "Context references" tab. Is there a way to add the system as a lifeline in sequence diagrams ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you "could" simply create a life line from the context menu and name it `System`. But that would make absolutely no sense. The system under consideration which is shown as boundary just is a placeholder or the borderline as to where the *real classes* that make up the system will stay. So, your actors will communicate with instances of the classes that you designed to make up the system under consideration.